# Change linux password and expire at the same time

Tags: bash, passwd

I'm learning Linux bash scripting and faced an error without notification. I would like to understand why I can't both change password and expire it at the same time? Additionally, there is no any error nor notification I do things wrong. Let's see:

```
# assuming root
USERNAME=foo
PASSWORD=bar
useradd -m $USERNAME
echo "$PASSWORD" | passwd -e --stdin $USERNAME
```

outputs:

```
Expiring password for user turing.
passwd: Success
```

But when I try `su - foo` with password "bar", I can't login. Only this one is correct:

```
# assuming root
USERNAME=foo
PASSWORD=bar
useradd -m $USERNAME
echo "$PASSWORD" | passwd --stdin $USERNAME
passwd -e $USERNAME
```

Can you please explain why?

Comment: Does the old password still work? I guess the `-e` flag will just exit `passwd` once the expiry is set and not update the password. How does `passwd --stdin -e $USERNAME` behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you must run two separate commands, per the source code of passwd at:

https://pagure.io/passwd/blob/master/f/passwd.c

Is that password expiry will always be checked before the --stdin flag, and will cause the main function to return, which essentially means program exit in this case.

```
if (passwd_flags & PASSWD_EXPIRE) {
        printf(_("Expiring password for user %s.\n"), username);
        retval = pwdb_update_aging(username, -2, -2, -2, -2, 0);
        printf("%s: %s\n", progname,
               retval ==
               0 ? _("Success") : _("Error"));
        audit_log_acct_message(audit_fd, AUDIT_USER_MGMT,
            NULL, "expired-password", NULL, pwd->pw_uid,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, retval == 0);
        return retval;
    }
```

The actual parsing of the command-line options occurs before this point, so order does not matter, the expiry flag will always be accounted for before the --stdin flag in this version of passwd.

This essential means you will always have to run `passwd -e <username>` and `passwd <username>` as separate commands, as it is not logically possible to do both expiry and password change within the same command syntax.